# Wso2 Logging in to a .NET application using the Identity

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

we trying to connect .net application with Wso2 identity but when i request the

https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token as following :

```
String clientId = txtClientId.Text;
            String clientSecret = txtSecret.Text;
            String grantType = txtgrantType.Text;
            String redirectUri = txtReqUri.Text;

            NameValueCollection param = new NameValueCollection();
            param.Add("client_id", clientId);
            param.Add("client_secret", clientSecret);
            param.Add("grant_type", grantType);
            param.Add("redirect_uri", redirectUri);
            param.Add("code", code);

            String serverUrl = "https://localhost:9443/";
            WebClient client = new WebClient();

            //Call the token endpoint and acess the token details
            var result = client.UploadValues(serverUrl + "oauth2/token", param);
```

we get problem **The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel**
we included the certification in our .net application as you can see in image below, could you please give me the configuration of the default certification **wso2carbon.jks**

[image]

Comment: you've just included the carbon.jks in your project and do you expect it to work itself?

Comment: what do you mean "configuration of the default certification wso2carbon.jks"?

Answer (score 1):

> The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

Seems (as you as well found out) your .net application is calling the identity server snd the client doesn't trust the SSL certificate provided by the identity server.

Simple workaround - when having the server on the same private network, you could as well use HTTP protocol (assuming the communication is secured on different perimeter): http://is_hostname:8280/token

Correct solution - use SSL with qualified certificates. For the start lets get it working with the current provided certificate

> we included the certification in our .net application as you can see in image below, could you please give me the configuration of the default certification wso2carbon.jks

you've just dropped the carbon.jks file in your project and do you expect it to work itself?? (JKS is Java KeyStore)

The certificate is self-signed custom certificate (not signed by any trusted CA) with domain name `CN=localhost`

To get the default certificate trusted you need to enforce:

1. The client needs to trust the server's certificate
2. The client must not validate the domain name (if it's not localhost)

I must admin I am not .net programmer and I rather let you to search the net than provide you wrong answer for how to setup these points.

To export the certificate - the easies way is open the identity server's console and export the certificate from the browser. (or you could use `openssl s_client -connect server:port`, keytool or other tools)